# LINQ to SQL insert-if-non-existent

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'd like to know if there's an easier way to insert a record if it doesn't already exist in a table. I'm still trying to build my LINQ to SQL skills.

Here's what I've got, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

```
public static TEntity InsertIfNotExists<TEntity>
(
    DataContext db,
    Table<TEntity> table,
    Func<TEntity,bool> where,
    TEntity record
)
    where TEntity : class
{
    TEntity existing = table.SingleOrDefault<TEntity>(where);

    if (existing != null)
    {
        return existing; 
    }
    else
    {
        table.InsertOnSubmit(record);

        // Can't use table.Context.SubmitChanges()
        // 'cause it's read-only

        db.SubmitChanges();
    }

    return record;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public static void InsertIfNotExists<TEntity>
                    (this Table<TEntity> table,
                     TEntity entity,
                     Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>> predicate)
    where TEntity : class
{ 
    if (!table.Any(predicate)) 
    {
        table.InsertOnSubmit(record);
        table.Context.SubmitChanges();
    }
 }


table.InsertIfNotExists(entity, e=>e.BooleanProperty);
```

Comment: What is e => e.BooleanProperty? Entities do not have a BooleanProperty member. I've never seen this before...

Comment: Hmm, you'll notice that in my code, I said that table.Context.SubmitChanges() didn't work because it's get-only. Apparently I made a mistake.

Comment: e=>e.BooleanProperty is just an example. It can stand for any expression that returns a boolean value.

Comment: One last question (thanks for your help, by the way!). What is the benefit of using Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>> of just Func<TEntity,bool>? I see to recall something about "compiled expressions." When should I wrap a Func<> in an Expression<>, and can Action<>s be wrapped too?

Comment: If you use Expression, it'll be converted to SQL and executed in the database. A naked Func can load the whole table into memory. Any delegate type can be used for an Expression< T>.

Comment: Does this not create a race condition? Something else could change the database after the Any() and before the SubmitChanges() call?

Answer (score 12):

As others have pointed out, the `if (!Any()) { InsertOnSubmit(); }` solutions all have a race condition. If you go that route, when you call `SubmitChanges`, you have to take into account  that either a) a `SqlException` could be raised for a duplicate insert, or b) you could have duplicate records in the table.

Fortunately, we can use the database to avoid the race condition by enforcing uniqueness. The following code assumes that there is a primary key or unique constraint on the table to prevent the insertion of duplicate records.

```
using (var db = new DataContext()) {

    // Add the new (possibly duplicate) record to the data context here.

    try {
        db.SubmitChanges();
    } catch (SqlException ex) {
        const int violationOfPrimaryKeyContraint = 2627;
        const int violationOfUniqueConstraint = 2601;
        var duplicateRecordExceptionNumbers = new [] {
            violationOfPrimaryKeyContraint, violationOfUniqueConstraint
        };
        if (!duplicateRecordExceptionNumbers.Contains(ex.Number)) {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Now... things get a fair bit more complicated if you have to perform the insert in a batch transaction with other database updates.

Answer (score 5):

Agree with [marxidad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100068/linq-to-sql-insert-if-non-existent#100496), but see note 1.

Note 1: IMHO, it is not wise to call `db.SubmitChanges()` in a helper method, because you may break the context transaction. This means that if you call the `InsertIfNotExists<TEntity>` in the middle of a complex update of several entities you are saving the changes not at once but in steps.

Note 2: The `InsertIfNotExists<TEntity>` method is a very generic method that works for any scenario. If you want to just discriminate the entities that have loaded from the database from the entities that have been created from the code, you can utilize the partial method `OnLoaded` of the Entity class like this:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public bool IsLoaded { get; private set; }
    partial void OnLoaded()
    {
        IsLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

Given that (and note 1), then InsertIfNotExists functionality is reduced to the following:

```
if (!record.IsLoaded)
    db.InsertOnSubmit(record);
```

Comment: A better design might be for the method to be called InsertOnSubmitIfNotExists() and to leave out table.Context.SubmitChanges()

Answer (score 4):

Small modification for Mark's answer:

If you only care about checking if the entity exists by its primary key, Marke's answer can be used like this:

```
public static void InsertIfNotExists<TEntity>
                    (this Table<TEntity> table
                     , TEntity entity
                    ) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (!table.Contains(entity))
        {
            table.InsertOnSubmit(entity);

        }
    }
```