# C#: How to see if a Linq2SQL entity is in the database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I would like to check if an entity is already added to the database. So, how can I see this difference between `a` and `b`?

```
var a = dataContext.Things.First(x => x.Name == something);
var b = new Thing { Name = something };
```

To make it clearer, if I have this:

```
var thing = dataContext.Things.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == something) 
            ?? new Thing { Name = something };
```

How can I see if `thing` needs to be inserted?

Comment: I found a related question that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100068/linq-to-sql-insert-if-non-existent

Comment: Cool, will check that out as well then!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`, that will return `null` if there are no matches.

As for knowing whether you need to insert - just remember whether or not it was null to start with:

```
var a = dataContext.Things.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == something);
bool needsInsertion = (a == null);
a = a ?? new Thing { Name = something };
```

Alternatively, if there's an ID field in `Thing` which is automatically populated by the database, you can just use that to detect whether it's already in the database or not.

Comment: Yes, that I know. Maybe my question wasn't clear enough... I will elaborate in my question.

Comment: Is the id always 0 if not inserted? Or is it something else?