# Simultaneously click on button and data inserted with duplicate entry

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dotnetnuke

I have created a form in which there are two types of entry can insert data one is for registered users and another for unregistered data.

When I opened same `URL` on two different browser and fill the form with same data then click on submit button on both browser at same time then in `C#` code I am using transaction to avoid ambiguity but in this scenario both data is saved into database column.

I have tried so many stuff, put validation check before submit but still no positive feedback.

Please suggest me what should I do in this scenario?

Comment: why don't you verify data before insertion, whether its duplicate or not?

Comment: yes, i need to check if same is exists then i should not insert duplicate entry.

Answer (score 0):

While inserting data for particular user you can make additional check if there already data exist for that user. Insert only if there is no record exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the check and the insert into the same transaction. Otherwise 2 checks happening at the same time gets an OK back from the DB, and then both do the update and 1 fails.

Comment: Take a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100068/linq-to-sql-insert-if-non-existent

Answer (score 0):

Even if you update your code to check for the value before insert, another insert could happen before your insert.  If you really want to guarantee integrity of your data, you need to create some sort of constraint in your database that doesn't allow conflicting values.  This will often be a primary key, but when not, you can create a unique constraint across the columns where you don't want to allow duplicate values.  Then, you just need to handle the exception that may be raised by duplicate values.